# React Hooks: best practice to get user authenticated

Tags: reactjs

I am changing a React app from class based to function based. In the based class the declaration of listeners are in the lifecycle method componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getNotes()
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
        this.setState({user: user});
        this.createNoteListener = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateNote, { owner:this.state.user.username })).subscribe({
          next: noteData => {
            const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote
            const prevNotes = this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id)
            const updatedNotes = [...prevNotes, newNote]
            this.setState({ notes: updatedNotes })
        }
      })...
```

To unsubscribe the listener I use the lifecycle method:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.createNoteListener.unsubscribe()
```

Changing to a function based class the listener declaration is like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getNotes()
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
            const createNoteListener = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateNote, { owner: user.username })).subscribe({
                next: noteData => {
                    const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote
                    setNotes(prevNotes => {
                        const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id)
                        const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote]
                        return updatedNotes
                    })
                    setNote("")
                }
            ............
            return () => {
                createNoteListener.unsubscribe() //the error is here
            }
```

I am getting an erro saying: 'createNoteListener' is not defined.

Since I need the authenticated user to create the listener, how/where should I get/set the user before declaring the listener?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createNoteListener is defined in different scope.

Can you try this?

```
    useEffect(() => {
      getNotes()
      let createNoteListener = null;
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
           createNoteListener = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateNote, { owner: user.username })).subscribe({
              next: noteData => {
                  const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote
                  setNotes(prevNotes => {
                      const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id)
                      const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote]
                      return updatedNotes
                  })
                  setNote("")
              }
            }
         )}
        )

       return () => {
                createNoteListener.unsubscribe() //the error is here
            }
      } 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide an extra argument to the useEffect Hook
You can do this

```
useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
        const createNoteListener = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateNote, { owner: user.username })).subscribe({
            next: noteData => {
                const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote
                setNotes(prevNotes => {
                    const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id)
                    const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote]
                    return updatedNotes
                })
                setNote("")
            }
        ............
        return () => {
            createNoteListener.unsubscribe()
        }, []) // provide empty array as second argument
```

This is because you want to subscribe only once.

Hope it helps